# Unable to detect error in saving a nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, cocoon-gem

I am using the cocoon gem for nested forms. An accommodation_category can have many options. I made a form structure where users first create the accommodation_category and thereafter create options via a custom controller action.

Everything works as expected, however the nested option object(s) do(es) not save in my DB. I used cocoon for several other nested objects related to accommodation_category, however the options object is the only one which is not saving. I checked for 2 days, but cannot seem to find the error/typo in my code.

When running in my local environment I obtain a rollback when arrived at my accommodation_category.rb line 32

```
@accommodation_category = @accommodation_category.update_attributes(accommodation_category_params)
```

**TEXT TERMINAL RUNNING LOCALHOST:**

"Started PATCH "/parks/19/accommodation_categories/132" for ::1 at 2019-09-09 10:45:05 +0200

Processing by AccommodationCategoriesController#update as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"X+BFZCfDrY2iGq+wH4H4c/XieKoVaLMUTZlNUaNb65OAxcm09fw2HyKkU2biQttzEsIzL87FIJFOFENpvc652Q==", "accommodation_category"=>{"options_attributes"=>{"1568018703588"=>{"name"=>"1", "description"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "park_id"=>"19", "id"=>"132"}

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]

↳ /Users/xx/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Park Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "parks".* FROM "parks" WHERE "parks"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]

↳ app/controllers/accommodation_categories_controller.rb:29
  AccommodationCategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "accommodation_categories".* FROM "accommodation_categories" WHERE "accommodation_categories"."park_id" = $1 AND "accommodation_categories"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["park_id", 19], ["id", 132], ["LIMIT", 1]]

↳ app/controllers/accommodation_categories_controller.rb:30
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN

↳ app/controllers/accommodation_categories_controller.rb:32
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK

↳ app/controllers/accommodation_categories_controller.rb:32
  AccommodationCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "accommodation_categories".* FROM "accommodation_categories" WHERE "accommodation_categories"."park_id" = $1 AND "accommodation_categories"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["park_id", 19], ["id", 132], ["LIMIT", 1]]

↳ app/controllers/accommodation_categories_controller.rb:44

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/accommodation_categories/132/new_discounts
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
"

**END TEXT TERMINAL RUNNING LOCALHOST**

**Please find below the code of the app:**

accommodation_category.rb

```
class AccommodationCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park

  has_many :options, inverse_of: :accommodation_category, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['name'].blank? }
end
```

option.rb

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accommodation_category
end
```

accommodation_categories_controller.rb

```
class AccommodationCategoriesController < ApplicationController
[]
def new_options
    @accommodation_category = AccommodationCategory.find(params[:id])
    @park = @accommodation_category.park
    authorize @accommodation_category
  end

 def update
    @park = Park.find(params[:park_id])
    @accommodation_category = 
     @park.accommodation_categories.find(params[:id])
    authorize @accommodation_category
    @accommodation_category = 
  @accommodation_category.update_attributes(accommodation_category_params)
redirect_to root_path
end

private
  def accommodation_category_params
    params.require(:accommodation_category).permit(:name, :description, options_attributes: [:name, :description, :rank, _destroy])
  end
end
```

new_options.html.erb

```
<%= render 'options_new_form', park: @park%>
```

_option_new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@park, @accommodation_category] do |f|%>
<% f.fields_for :options do |option| %>
  <%= render 'option_fields', f: option %>
<% end %>

<div>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add option', f, :options %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_option_fields.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove option", f %>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you accommodation_category_params -- you didn't list that as part of the controller code?

Comment: Excuse me, just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error and @nathanvda was spot on, the params were not correct causing a rollback. I though it might be useful for others to describe how I found out for nested tables, using the cocoon gem.

1) I went to my console and tried creating a new accommodation_category with options, which caused the rollback.

```
cat11=AccommodationCategory.create(name:'hello', options_attributes:[{name:'option 1'}])
```

2) Then I checked if it was valid (obviously not)

```
cat11.valid?
```

3) Lastly, I displayed the error messages

```
cat11.errors.full_messages
=> ["Park must exist", "Options age table must exist", "Options price must exist"]
```

I'm pretty sure I did something wrong with the debugging @nathanvda mentioned, which should have given me the same error message. I fixed the errors by linking the price & age_table (which I should have posted in my question in the first place, but didn't because I deemed it not relevant).

Comment: I hope you still _also_ made sure that the code in the controller and views are also changed as I suggested, because there might be a time a user will generate incorrect input, causing a validation to fail, and then the user should be informed how they should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up. I indeed changed the code to capture these events as well;)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `inverse_of`

```
class AccommodationCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park

  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :accommodation_category
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['name'].blank? }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it's still not saving the option in the DB.

Comment: I tried dropping the option model entirely and start from scratch with the nested model, but I a still having the same problem of not saving. So think the error is more likely to be in the design of the programme than a type.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a failing validation, causing the `update_attributes` to rollback. Your (shown) controller-code does not handle any errors at all, I would expect something like:

```
 @accommodation_category.update_attributes(accommodation_category_params)
 if @accomodation.valid? 
   redirect_to root_path
 else
   render :edit
 end
```

Also, when rendering the form, it might be useful to show the validation errors. Simple-form will do this automatically for you (if the errors match to shown fields). Otherwise you could do something like

```
  = simple_form_for [@park, @accommodation_category] do |f|
    - if !@accomodation_category.valid?
      .alert.alert-error 
        Failed to save! Error:
        = @accomodation_category.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
```

(I use haml for brevity and clarity)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive elaboration + example. I tried debugging with simple_form, but surprisingly, there are no error messages. However following your reasoning, I tried getting rid of my blank? validating in the model and subsequently creating new (nested) options via the controller --> 3.times {@accommodation_category.options.build} I do get an error message saying "ActionController::ParameterMissing in AccommodationCategoriesController#update" AND "param is missing or the value is empty: accommodation_category" .

Comment: So finally some progress with a new error message:) I keep you guys posted if I find the error, as the 'not saving' problem seems to be caused by the program not properly recognising the relationship between options & accommodation_categories.

Comment: Can you show us what is posted to the controller? (it should be in the logfile, it should list all the params in one of the first lines when the action starts)..

Comment: If you mean the parameters that are being sent in the update controller, that log in is the question stated "Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"X+BFZCfDrY2iGq+wH4H4c/XieKoVaLMUTZlNUaNb65OAxcm09fw2HyKkU2biQttzEsIzL87FIJFOFENpvc652Q==", "accommodation_category"=>{"options_attributes"=>{"1568018703588"=>{"name"=>"1", "description"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "park_id"=>"19", "id"=>"132"}"

Comment: I finally found it, see my complete answer below. Thank you so much for the support!